# ASP MVC error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

My view

```
<table>
                 <tr>
        <td>
            Middle Name : 
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => @Model.EmployeeDetail.MiddleName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => @Model.EmployeeDetail.MiddleName)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Last Name : 
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => @Model.EmployeeDetail.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => @Model.EmployeeDetail.LastName)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Date of Birth  : 
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => @Model.EmployeeDetail.DateOfBirth)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => @Model.EmployeeDetail.DateOfBirth)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My Controller action

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var id = 0;
        if (Session["id"] != null)
        {
            id = Convert.ToInt32((Session["id"].ToString()));
        }
        var empDetails = _empRepository.GetEmployeeDetails(id);
        var emp = new UserViewModel { EmployeeDetail = empDetails };
        return View(emp);
    }
```

My viewmodel

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public EmployeeDetail EmployeeDetail { get; set; }
}
```

my model

```
public partial class EmployeeDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

In my view I am getting object reference at                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => @Model.EmployeeDetail.DateOfBirth)

I am getting this error due to viewmodel "emp" which I am passing to view from controller action is null as I dont have any data in database for that particular Id.

How can I avoid this object reference error.

Comment: Try replacing `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => @Model.EmployeeDetail.DateOfBirth)` with `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeDetail.DateOfBirth)` and replace the other syntaxes as well

Comment: Is `Session["id"]` valid? It has data?

Comment: If you dont have any data in `emp`, you can check in your View like this : `if(Model !=null){ //here you write all your view code }else { @: The Model is Empty }`

Comment: I think your session is null... So you try to find record that has id=0

Comment: Probably `_empRepository.GetEmployeeDetails(id);` is returning `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => @Model.EmployeeDetail.DateOfBirth)
```

use

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeDetail.DateOfBirth)
```

You should do it for all lines...

```
 @Html.SomethingFor(model => model.EmployeeDetail.Something) // Not @Model.Something
```

UPDATE:

Don't let EmployeeDetail to be null.

```
public class UserViewModel
{
     private EmployeeDetail _employeeDetail = new EmployeeDetail();

     public EmployeeDetail EmployeeDetail 
     { 
        get { return _employeeDetail; }
        set { _employeeDetail = value ?? new EmployeeDetail(); } 
     }
}
```